# Linq on Complex XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Hi I Have the following XML

```
<Feed>
<Control>
        <Username>Fnol13</Username>
        <Password>12345</Password>          
</Control>
<Repairer>
        <RepairerName>Test</RepairerName>
        <RepairerAddress>Test</RepairerAddress>
        <RepairerTelephone>Test</RepairerTelephone>
</Repairer>
</Feed>
```

And a Model Class Containing following Properties

```
[Serializable]
public  class Job {

    public string Username { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string Reference { get; set; }

    public string RepairerAddress { get; set; }

    public string RepairerTelephone { get; set; }


}
```

I am using following Linq Query to Extract Data from XML

```
var results = from job in xmlDoc.Descendants("Control")
                      select new Job {
                          Username = (string)job.Element("Username").Value,
                          Password = (string)job.Element("Password").Value


                      };
// Here I want to add as well Descendants("Repairer") using same query

        return results.ToList();
```

Problem is that can return **Descendants("Control")** However I would like to get also Descendants("Repairer") and return in a same list as my model is showing. Could you please help me to write Linq Query and I am confirming you I am very new in Linq.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538645/linq-to-xml-via-c-sharp?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Model `Job` looks confusing to me because you may have multiple `Control` & 
`Repairer` nodes in which case it should map to a collection. Anyways for current XML I assume you need the elements of first `Repairer` node, you can achieve it like this:-

```
var results = from job in xmlDoc.Root.Elements("Control")
              let Repairer = job.Parent.Elements("Repairer").FirstOrDefault()
              select new Job
                   {
                      Username = (string)job.Element("Username"),
                      Password = (string)job.Element("Password"),
                      RepairerName = (string)Repairer.Element("RepairerName"),
                      RepairerAddress = (string)Repairer.Element("RepairerAddress"),
                      RepairerTelephone = (string)Repairer.Element("RepairerTelephone")
                   };
```

Also, note `(string)job.Element("Username")` will give you the node value. There is no need to call the `Value` property.

**Update:**

You can use `XDocument` when working with LINQ-to-XML:-

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(XMLpath);
```

Comment: Thank you Rahul; 
Could you please tell me Assembly Reference for Root.Element("Control") because I am having error System.Xml.Linq.XElement does not contain a definition for Root ....

Comment: I have something like that and getting error on Root.Element 
XElement xmlDoc = XElement.Load(path);
 var results = from job in xmlDoc.Root.Elements("Control")
           .....

Comment: Thank you that problem solved but now having {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."} while executing the query

Comment: @Rubel - You need to debug and see if the XML is loading in `XDocument ` object. Your XML is working fine for me with this code. Either you have some typo somewhere or XML is not loading properly, make sure you pass the full xml path in `Load` method of `XDocument `.

Comment: Thank you @Rahul, You are a legend. Work perfect :)

Comment: Hi @Rahul could you please also help me to solve : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34026112/extract-data-from-complex-xml-using-linq

Comment: Thank you Rahul, having an error there; added into comment, could you please have a look, many thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like -

```
Reference = (string)job.Parent.Descendants("Repairer").FirstOrDefault().Element("RepairerAddress").Value;
```