# Extract data from complex XML using Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Hi I Have a XML Like Follows

```
<Feed>
<Control>
    <UserName>testUser</UserName>
    <Password>testPass</Password>
</Control>
<leeds>
    <leed>
        <leedid>4990935</leedid>
        <Reference>4990935</Reference>
        <AccidentDetails>
            <IncidentDate>2015-08-05</IncidentDate>
            <AccidentDetails>damage</AccidentDetails>
        </AccidentDetails>
        <ClientDetails>
            <ClientsID>4990935</ClientsID>
            <ClientsName>Test Name</ClientsName>
        </ClientDetails>
        <IncidentDetails>
            <IncidentID>557475</IncidentID>
            <IncidentName>Injury</IncidentName>
        </IncidentDetails>
    </leed>
<leed>
.......... More Leeds 
</leed>
```

Now I am trying to Extract Data Using the Following Linq but its not working could you please help.

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(path);

        var results = from job in xmlDoc.Root.Elements("Control")
                      let Repairer = job.Parent.Elements("Leeds").FirstOrDefault()

                      select new Job {
                          Username = (string)job.Element("leedid"),
                          Password = (string)job.Element("Reference"),
                          IncidentDetail = (string)job.Element("IncidentDetail"),
                          ClientsName = (string)job.Element("ClientsName"),
                          IncidentName = (string)Repairer.Element("IncidentName")
                      };
                      return result;
```

I have Model Class

```
public class Control {
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public Leed leeds {get; set;}
} 

public class Leed {

    public int leedid { get; set; }

    public int Reference { get; set; }

    public string IncidentDate { get; set; }

    public string IncidentDetail { get; set; }

    public string ClientsID { get; set; }

    public string ClientsName { get; set; }

    public string IncidentID { get; set; }

    public string IncidentName { get; set; }
}
```

I am very new in Linq and XML, One Feed will have one control and multiple leeds.

Comment: Which data are you interested in? What does not work?

Comment: The linq query I wrote is returning only control not leeds

Comment: I think my model class is also wrong

Comment: it should have 2 model class 
One for Control and another one list of Leeds

Comment: Your xml is invalid. Your code does not make sense (each job is a Control element, which does not have "leedid", etc. elements), and your Repairer selection doesn't make sense either (there is no element "Leeds" anywhere - are you unaware that the element names are case sensitive?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your XML, your `Control` class in not correct. Since you may have multiple `leed` tags inside `leeds` so you should have similar mapping in your `Control` class, so change it to accept a collection instead like this:-

```
 public List<Leed> leeds { get; set; }
```

Now, store the `leeds` node inside a local variable `leeds`, finally loop again for multiple `leeds`.

This should give you the expected output:-

```
List<Control> result = (from job in xdoc.Root.Elements("Control")
         let leeds = job.Parent.Element("leeds")
         select new Control
            {
               Username = (string)job.Element("UserName"),
               Password = (string)job.Element("Password"),
               leeds = (from leed in leeds.Elements("leed")
                     let AccidentDtls = leed.Element("AccidentDetails")
                     let ClientDetails = leed.Element("ClientDetails")
                     let IncidentDtls = leed.Element("IncidentDetails")
                     select new Leed
                        {
                          leedid = (int)leed.Element("leedid"),
                          Reference = (int)leed.Element("Reference"),
                          IncidentDate = (string)AccidentDtls.Element("IncidentDate"),
                          IncidentDetail = (string)AccidentDtls.Element("IncidentDetail"),
                          ClientsID = (string)ClientDetails.Element("ClientsID"),
                          ClientsName = (string)ClientDetails.Element("ClientsName"),
                          IncidentID = (string)IncidentDtls.Element("IncidentID"),
                          IncidentName = (string)IncidentDtls.Element("IncidentName")
                        }).ToList()
           }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you Rahul, having Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<CVS_Export.Model.Leed>' to 'CVS_Export.Model.Leed'

Comment: @Rubel - Post the complete exception. It cannot convert `List<T>` to what? Have you updated your `Control` class as I mentioned in the answer?

Comment: Sorry I missed that part; You are a legend

Comment: Hi @Rahul once again: Could you please help me to solve the problem on : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34207270/add-elements-and-node-in-xml

Comment: @Rubel - Sure let me check.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change a lot of things to get it to work.  Tag names must be in the same upper/lower case letters as xml

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml =
               "<Feed>" +
                  "<Control>" +
                    "<UserName>testUser</UserName>" +
                    "<Password>testPass</Password>" +
                  "</Control>" +
                  "<leeds>" +
                    "<leed>" +
                      "<leedid>4990935</leedid>" +
                      "<Reference>4990935</Reference>" +
                      "<IncidentDetails>" +
                        "<IncidentDate>2015-08-05</IncidentDate>" +
                        "<AccidentDetails>damage</AccidentDetails>" +
                      "</IncidentDetails>>" +
                        "<ClientDetails>" +
                          "<ClientsID>4990935</ClientsID>" +
                          "<ClientsName>Test Name</ClientsName>" +
                        "</ClientDetails>" +
                        "<IncidentDetails>" +
                          "<IncidentID>557475</IncidentID>" +
                          "<IncidentName>Injury</IncidentName>" +
                        "</IncidentDetails>" +
                      "</leed>" +
                  "</leeds>" +
                "</Feed>";
            XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            var results = xmlDoc.Descendants("Feed").Select(feed => 
                          feed.Descendants("leed").Select(job => new Job
                          {
                              Username = (string)feed.Elements("Control").FirstOrDefault().Element("UserName"),
                              Password = (string)feed.Elements("Control").FirstOrDefault().Element("Password"),
                              IncidentDetail = string.Join(",", job.Element("IncidentDetails").Elements().Select(x => x.Value)),
                              ClientsName = (string)job.Elements("ClientsName").FirstOrDefault(),
                              IncidentName = (string)job.Descendants("IncidentName").FirstOrDefault()
                          }).ToList()).ToList();
        }
    }
    public class Job
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }

        public string Password { get; set; }

        public int leedid { get; set; }

        public int Reference { get; set; }

        public string IncidentDate { get; set; }

        public string IncidentDetail { get; set; }

        public string ClientsID { get; set; }

        public string ClientsName { get; set; }

        public string IncidentID { get; set; }

        public string IncidentName { get; set; }
    }
}

​
```

Comment: What happens if there is more than one `leed` collection?  Are you intending to flatten out the XML in your model, or would you be better served with two models - the Control model, that contains a collection of Leed models?

Comment: Hi @Tim thank you very much for your solution. Certainly I will have Multiple Leeds Inside Leed tag, Don't know how can I handle this. Could you please help

Comment: Made requested changes