# Parsing Complex XML with C# LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, ssis

I am using c# and LINQ in a script transformation in VS2012 to parse a complex xml soap message. I cannot figure out how to loop through the xml and get all the elements that I want in a single row. The xml is below. This is only a portion of what is returned. There are 48 intervals for each item and generally 5-6 items.

```
<return>
<item>
    <interval>
        <intervalDate>
            <day>8</day>
            <month>7</month>
            <year>2016</year>
        </intervalDate>
        <intervalTime>
            <hours>0</hours>
            <militaryTime>true</militaryTime>
            <minutes>0</minutes>
            <seconds>0</seconds>
        </intervalTime>
        <laborType>forecasted</laborType>
        <volume>0.0</volume>
    </interval>
    <interval>
        <intervalDate>
            <day>8</day>
            <month>7</month>
            <year>2016</year>
        </intervalDate>
        <intervalTime>
            <hours>0</hours>
            <militaryTime>true</militaryTime>
            <minutes>30</minutes>
            <seconds>0</seconds>
        </intervalTime>
        <laborType>forecasted</laborType>
        <volume>0.0</volume>
    </interval>
    <jobCode>1</jobCode>
    <jobName>SERVER</jobName>
</item>
<item>
    <interval>
        <intervalDate>
            <day>8</day>
            <month>7</month>
            <year>2016</year>
        </intervalDate>
        <intervalTime>
            <hours>0</hours>
            <militaryTime>true</militaryTime>
            <minutes>0</minutes>
            <seconds>0</seconds>
        </intervalTime>
        <laborType>forecasted</laborType>
        <volume>0.0</volume>
    </interval>
    <interval>
        <intervalDate>
            <day>8</day>
            <month>7</month>
            <year>2016</year>
        </intervalDate>
        <intervalTime>
            <hours>0</hours>
            <militaryTime>true</militaryTime>
            <minutes>30</minutes>
            <seconds>0</seconds>
        </intervalTime>
        <laborType>forecasted</laborType>
        <volume>0.0</volume>
    </interval>
    <jobCode>50</jobCode>
    <jobName>Cashier</jobName>
</item>
```

I need to output the data into 5 columns, datetime, laborType, laborVolume, laborJobCode, and laborJobName.

laborDateTime|laborType|laborVolume|laborJobCode|laborJobName

2016-08-07 00:00:00.000|forecasted|0|1|SERVER

2016-08-07 00:30:00.000|forecasted|0|1|SERVER

2016-08-07 01:00:00.000|forecasted|0|1|SERVER

2016-08-07 01:30:00.000|forecasted|0|1|SERVER

I have not been able to find any examples online that show how to do this. If I loop through Interval, I return the expected number of rows but have no way of getting the JobCode and JobName.

```
    public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
{
    /*
      Add rows by calling the AddRow method on the member variable named "<Output Name>Buffer".
      For example, call MyOutputBuffer.AddRow() if your output was named "MyOutput".
    */

    String content = Variables.XMLString;

    XElement xdoc = XElement.Parse(content);

    var Interval = from interval in xdoc.Descendants("interval")
                   select new
                   {
                             laborIntervalDay = interval.Element("intervalDate").Element("day").Value,
                             laborIntervalMonth = interval.Element("intervalDate").Element("month").Value,
                             laborIntervalYear = interval.Element("intervalDate").Element("year").Value,
                             laborIntervalHour = interval.Element("intervalTime").Element("hours").Value,
                             laborIntervalMinutes = interval.Element("intervalTime").Element("minutes").Value,
                             laborIntervalSeconds = interval.Element("intervalTime").Element("seconds").Value,
                             laborIntervalMilitary = interval.Element("intervalTime").Element("militaryTime").Value,
                             laborType = interval.Element("laborType").Value,
                             laborVolume = interval.Element("volume").Value
                   };


            foreach (var q in Interval)
            {
                try
                {
                    DateTime dtBusinessDate = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(q.laborIntervalYear), Convert.ToInt32(q.laborIntervalMonth), Convert.ToInt32(q.laborIntervalDay), Convert.ToInt32(q.laborIntervalHour), Convert.ToInt32(q.laborIntervalMinutes), Convert.ToInt32(q.laborIntervalSeconds));
                    OUTLaborBuffer.AddRow();
                    OUTLaborBuffer.laborDateTime = dtBusinessDate;
                    OUTLaborBuffer.laborType = Convert.ToString(q.laborType);
                    OUTLaborBuffer.laborVolume = Convert.ToDouble(q.laborVolume);
                    //OUTLaborBuffer.laborJobCode = Convert.ToInt64(p.laborJobCode);
                    //OUTLaborBuffer.laborJobName = p.laborJobName;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error Message: " + ex.Message + " Message Detail: " + ex.StackTrace);
                }
            }

    }
```

I've also tried looping through Labor and Interval but this is not correct because it is assigning the JobCode/JobName of the current iteration of Labor to all intervals. If there are 5 items then I end up with 5x the expected rows.

```
        var Interval = from interval in xdoc.Descendants("interval")
                   select new
                   {
                             laborIntervalDay = interval.Element("intervalDate").Element("day").Value,
                             laborIntervalMonth = interval.Element("intervalDate").Element("month").Value,
                             laborIntervalYear = interval.Element("intervalDate").Element("year").Value,
                             laborIntervalHour = interval.Element("intervalTime").Element("hours").Value,
                             laborIntervalMinutes = interval.Element("intervalTime").Element("minutes").Value,
                             laborIntervalSeconds = interval.Element("intervalTime").Element("seconds").Value,
                             laborIntervalMilitary = interval.Element("intervalTime").Element("militaryTime").Value,
                             laborType = interval.Element("laborType").Value,
                             laborVolume = interval.Element("volume").Value
                   };

    var Labor = from item in xdoc.Descendants("item")
                         select new
                         {
                             laborJobCode = item.Element("jobCode").Value,
                             laborJobName = item.Element("jobName").Value,
                         };

    foreach (var p in Labor)
    {
        // Save check information
        try
        {

            foreach (var q in Interval)
            {
                try
                {
                    DateTime dtBusinessDate = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(q.laborIntervalYear), Convert.ToInt32(q.laborIntervalMonth), Convert.ToInt32(q.laborIntervalDay), Convert.ToInt32(q.laborIntervalHour), Convert.ToInt32(q.laborIntervalMinutes), Convert.ToInt32(q.laborIntervalSeconds));
                    OUTLaborBuffer.AddRow();
                    OUTLaborBuffer.laborDateTime = dtBusinessDate;
                    OUTLaborBuffer.laborType = Convert.ToString(q.laborType);
                    OUTLaborBuffer.laborVolume = Convert.ToDouble(q.laborVolume);
                    OUTLaborBuffer.laborJobCode = Convert.ToInt64(p.laborJobCode);
                    OUTLaborBuffer.laborJobName = p.laborJobName;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error Message: " + ex.Message + " Message Detail: " + ex.StackTrace);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error Message: " + ex.Message + " Message Detail: " + ex.StackTrace);
        }

    }


}
```

I have found some examples online showing of complex xml being parsed like below:

```
        var Labor = from item in xdoc.Descendants("item")
                         select new
                         {
                             laborJobCode = item.Element("jobCode").Value,
                             laborJobName = item.Element("jobName").Value,
                             laborInterval = (from interval in xdoc.Descendants("interval")
                                              select new
                                              {
                                                laborIntervalDay = interval.Element("intervalDate").Element("day").Value,
                                                laborIntervalMonth = interval.Element("intervalDate").Element("month").Value,
                                                laborIntervalYear = interval.Element("intervalDate").Element("year").Value,
                                                laborIntervalHour = interval.Element("intervalTime").Element("hours").Value,
                                                laborIntervalMinutes = interval.Element("intervalTime").Element("minutes").Value,
                                                laborIntervalSeconds = interval.Element("intervalTime").Element("seconds").Value,
                                                laborIntervalMilitary = interval.Element("intervalTime").Element("militaryTime").Value,
                                                laborType = interval.Element("laborType").Value,
                                                laborVolume = interval.Element("volume").Value
                                              })
                         };
```

The examples I've found with this structure are outputting ToList and I can't figure out how to output the descendants of interval in this format. Do you have any idea how this can be done?

Comment: In your last attempt try to replace `xdoc.Descendants("interval")` with `item.Descendants("interval")` and also add `.ToArray()` just to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using parent to get the JobCode and JobName while looping through intervals. I based it off of on this example: [Linq on Complex XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34018176/linq-on-complex-xml?rq=1)

Here is the code I ended up with:

```
public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
{
    /*
      Add rows by calling the AddRow method on the member variable named "<Output Name>Buffer".
      For example, call MyOutputBuffer.AddRow() if your output was named "MyOutput".
    */

    String content = Variables.XMLString;

    XElement xdoc = XElement.Parse(content);

    var Interval = from interval in xdoc.Descendants("interval")
                   select new
                   {
                       laborJobCode = interval.Parent.Element("jobCode").Value,
                       laborJobName = interval.Parent.Element("jobName").Value,
                       laborIntervalDay = interval.Element("intervalDate").Element("day").Value,
                       laborIntervalMonth = interval.Element("intervalDate").Element("month").Value,
                       laborIntervalYear = interval.Element("intervalDate").Element("year").Value,
                       laborIntervalHour = interval.Element("intervalTime").Element("hours").Value,
                       laborIntervalMinutes = interval.Element("intervalTime").Element("minutes").Value,
                       laborIntervalSeconds = interval.Element("intervalTime").Element("seconds").Value,
                       laborIntervalMilitary = interval.Element("intervalTime").Element("militaryTime").Value,
                       laborType = interval.Element("laborType").Value,
                       laborVolume = interval.Element("volume").Value
                   };

    foreach (var q in Interval) 
        {
            try
                {
                    DateTime dtBusinessDate = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(q.laborIntervalYear), Convert.ToInt32(q.laborIntervalMonth), Convert.ToInt32(q.laborIntervalDay), Convert.ToInt32(q.laborIntervalHour), Convert.ToInt32(q.laborIntervalMinutes), Convert.ToInt32(q.laborIntervalSeconds));
                    OUTLaborBuffer.AddRow();
                    OUTLaborBuffer.laborDateTime = dtBusinessDate;
                    OUTLaborBuffer.laborType = Convert.ToString(q.laborType);
                    OUTLaborBuffer.laborVolume = Convert.ToDouble(q.laborVolume);
                    OUTLaborBuffer.laborJobCode = Convert.ToInt64(q.laborJobCode);
                    OUTLaborBuffer.laborJobName =  Convert.ToString(q.laborJobName);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error Message: " + ex.Message + " Message Detail: " + ex.StackTrace);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
    public dynamic OUTLaborBuffer;
    public dynamic Variables;

    public void CreateNewOutputRows()
    {
        String content = Variables.XMLString;
        XElement data = XElement.Parse(content);

        foreach (var item in data.XPathSelectElements("//item"))
        {
            var jobCode = item.Element("jobCode").Value;
            var jobName = item.Element("jobName").Value;

            foreach (var interval in item.XPathSelectElements("//interval"))
            {
                var laborIntervalDay = interval.Element("intervalDate").Element("day").Value;
                var laborIntervalMonth = interval.Element("intervalDate").Element("month").Value;
                var laborIntervalYear = interval.Element("intervalDate").Element("year").Value;
                var laborIntervalHour = interval.Element("intervalTime").Element("hours").Value;
                var laborIntervalMinutes = interval.Element("intervalTime").Element("minutes").Value;
                var laborIntervalSeconds = interval.Element("intervalTime").Element("seconds").Value;
                var laborIntervalMilitary = interval.Element("intervalTime").Element("militaryTime").Value;
                var laborType = interval.Element("laborType").Value;
                var laborVolume = interval.Element("volume").Value;

                DateTime dtBusinessDate = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(laborIntervalYear), Convert.ToInt32(laborIntervalMonth), Convert.ToInt32(q.laborIntervalDay), Convert.ToInt32(laborIntervalHour), Convert.ToInt32(laborIntervalMinutes), Convert.ToInt32(laborIntervalSeconds));
                OUTLaborBuffer.AddRow();
                OUTLaborBuffer.laborDateTime = dtBusinessDate;
                OUTLaborBuffer.laborType = Convert.ToString(laborType);
                OUTLaborBuffer.laborVolume = Convert.ToDouble(laborVolume);
                OUTLaborBuffer.laborJobCode = Convert.ToInt64(jobCode);
                OUTLaborBuffer.laborJobName = jobName;
            }
        }
    }
```

feel free to change XPathSelectElements back to Descendants

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. Your code makes sense to me, but when I tried the code I am not getting any data coming through the task. There are no errors, but no data. Any ideas?

Comment: Try adding a breakpoint just to see if it gets to the AddRow and verify the data you have there. (And don't forget to remove the dynamic objects > I only added those so I wound't get errors in VS since I do not have those types)

Comment: I removed the dynamic objects and am still getting nothing. I put break points and message boxes but nothing shows up. The task completes instantaneously and goes to the next step.